# Android How to use string resource in gradle file

Tags: android, gradle, resources

On [this](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning.html) page, it is written:

> versionName — A string used as the version number shown to users.
>   This setting can be specified as a raw string or as a reference to a
>   string resource.

I would like to use a resource as version number. Something like @string/version .

What's the way ?

Thanks

Julien

Comment: You can check this if you have `productFlavour` on different variants and dimensions
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36105494/localizing-string-resources-added-via-build-gradle-using-resvalue

Answer (score 5):

I have create method using @Yaroslav's answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/37432654/6711554). Here is code of setting package name from string file.

```
def getPackageName() {
  try {
     def stringsFile = file("./src/main/res/values/string.xml")
     return new XmlParser().parse(stringsFile).string.find { it.@name.equals 'your_package_name' }.text()
  }catch(e){
     println(e)
     return "default.packagename"
  }
}
```

and use it like

```
 applicationId getPackageName()
```

You can read any string in your gradle from your any resource file.

Comment: Are all this code entered into build.gradle? I cannot get it to work... I placed def at the top and replaced `applicationId "com.test.test` with `applicationId getPackageName()`

Answer (score 0):

Try the following and sync your project with Gradle by clicking on the "Sync Now" button or by selecting "File" -> "Sync Project with Gradle Files" from the menu.

```
android {
    // ...

    defaultConfig {
        // The @string-resource only in single quotation marks!
        resValue "string", "<your_variable_name>", '@string/<your_string_resource_name>'
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

There is a similar question, which is already answered - [Android Gradle Read App Name from strings.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31122966/android-gradle-read-app-name-from-strings-xml). @SamuilYanovski offers to use configuration file like gradle.properties instead of trying to access Android resources from gradle file.